# How are YouTube videos selected for inclusion in Google Maps?

Tags: youtube, video, google-maps

Apart from geolocating videos via your YouTube account, is there any other process involved in getting them shown on the 'More... videos' overlay in Google Maps?

Edit:

As well as geolocating a test video, I've embedded it in a [public Google map](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=109204225032130278087.000482517a66365f4d14b&t=h&z=19). It's been there since the end of March 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I believe right now the only way is by geolocating videos or by [embedding the video into a map you have created](http://earth.google.com/outreach/tutorial_youtube.html).

Comment: Hmmm, I have a public Google map with video embedded in a placemark. It's been there for 3 months so I suspect there's human intervention at Google's end.

Answer (score 0):

I think just under edit you have to choose on the map where you filmed the video and google maps will pick it up automatically.